# Python BeautifulSoup only get 1 item from every page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Im working on a web crawler in python with the BeautifulSoup framework.
I get the right information from the target page. But it gets only 1 item from every page.

my code look like:

```
import csv
import time
import bs4 as bs
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

for i in range(1, 5):
   site = "XXURLXX".format(i)
   hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
   req = Request(site, headers=hdr)
   page = urlopen(req)
   soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')

data = []

for get_info in soup:
    name_box = soup.find('h2', attrs={'class': 'post-title'})
    name = name_box.text.strip()


    url_box = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'post-excerpt-download'})
    url = url_box.get('href')

data.append((name, url, site))

time.sleep(1)

print(data)

with open('stellarismods.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for url in data:
        writer.writerow([name, url, site])
```

I have already try to forloop

```
for name_box in soup.find('h2', attrs={'class': 'post-title'}):
       name = name_box.text.strip()


for url_box in soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'post-excerpt-download'}):
    url = url_box.get('href')
```

But i still get only 1 item from every page.

Comment: what is the point of the first `for` loop?

Comment: put a sample of the html you are getting

Comment: `find` returns 1st matched element, use `select` or `find_all` and then iterate the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) function. It will look for all elements you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the respone. But when i do that i get the followint error:
"AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"

When i print "url_box" i get the following result:

"[<a class="post-excerpt-download" href="##URL##" target="_blank">Download</a>, <a class="post-excerpt-download" href="##URL##" target="_blank">Download/a>]"

But when i print "url" i get the error above.

Comment: @J.Martin Function`find()` returns string. Function `find_all()` returns list. You have to use for loop.